# How to compare table column to parameter argument using SQL functions with HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

We use UUIDs as a binary to guard against SQL injection or guessing IDs.  As part of upgrading Spring Boot and Hibernate versions, I'm trying to move a custom dialect SQL function directly into a @Query, and getting this error:

`Parameter 1 of function 'left()' has type 'STRING', but argument is of type 'java.lang.Object'`

My query is as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM #{#entityName} p WHERE LEFT(HEX(p.uuid), 32) = LEFT(HEX(:searchUuid), 32)")
Optional<T> findByUuid(@Param("searchUuid") UUID searchUuid);
```

Can I accomplish this in the Query, or can this only be done with a custom function on the DB / within a dialect?